# How to remove a message from a select menu

Tags: php, jquery, html

In a `<select>` feature below I display a message if there are no modules with in the select menu:

```
    $moduleSELECT = '<select name="moduletextarea" id="moduleselect" size="3">'.PHP_EOL;      

    if($modulenum == 0){

    $moduleSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Modules currently on this Course</option>";

}else{

....
```

Now what I want to do is by using jquery, if I append a module into the select menu then it displays the module in the select menu:

```
        var selectedOption = jQuery("#modulesDrop option:selected");
        selectedOption.appendTo($("#moduleselect"));
```

But what I want to do in my jquery is that if the user appends the module into the select menu but the `No Modules currently on this Course` is showing, then I want it to remove that message from the select menu when the module is appended. But how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove you can use jquery `remove()`.

**it removes the set of matched elements from the DOM.**

http://api.jquery.com/remove/.

assuming your option(you want to remove) has a class red....

try this..

```
$('option.red', 'select').remove()​ //OR
$('option.red', '#moduleselect').remove()  // selector as id
```

after the module is appended..

here is an example in jsfiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/hgawb/

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're appending a new option to `moduleselect`, you could remove any instance of an option with `disabled="disabled"`:

```
$('#moduleselect option[disabled="disabled"]').remove();
```

You may want to identify the option element to remove differently if you have other disabled options in your menu. The above code would remove all of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/RHSCA/